# How to tag questions about processor instruction sets (machine code)?

Tags: discussion, tags

After asking [two](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1630/278) [questions](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1610/278) that are each missing this tag, and not knowing what to name it, I have brought this to meta. What should the tag used for questions about the instruction sets of processors be named?

Some suggestions so far include:
[instruction-set-architecture](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instruction-set-architecture), [cpu-architecture](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpu-architecture) [(both suggested by mnem)](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/2565), [opcode](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opcode) and [instruction-set](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instruction-set).

Answer (score 5):

In the case of the PDP question, I think [instruction-set](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instruction-set) is an excellent tag since that's what the question is specifically dealing with.

For the Z80 vs 8080 question though, I think the argument could be made for an [instruction-set-architecture](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instruction-set-architecture) tag since the question is comparing two separate (albeit similar) instruction sets and "instruction set architecture" refers to the specific design and implementation of a particular instruction set.

In fact, in the CPU design world, there is a team member (or members) responsible for creating the instruction set for a new processor who is referred to as the "instruction set architect".

Answer (score 4):

For this usage I would go for [instruction-set](/questions/tagged/instruction-set) for preference.

[opcode](/questions/tagged/opcode) implies a question about the behaviour or use of a specific instruction rather than the set as a whole.

[instruction-set-architecture](/questions/tagged/instruction-set-architecture) is a bit wordy and, to me, evokes memories of the Motorola v Intel architecture wars of the 1980s - 90s.  Should an instruction set be orthogonal or not.  Also CISC v RISC, etc.

[cpu-architecture](/questions/tagged/cpu-architecture) could encompass more than just the instruction set.  It could cover all aspects of the design.